# Compose pdf with the random variable itself and conditional probability.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

When I discussed with my classmates, we was wondering whether the following statement is correct.

Given $(X_k)_k$ be a discrete real-valued stochastic process and assume $p_{X_k}$ be the strictly positive pdf of $X_k$. Assume $I_i,I_j\subset \mathbb{R}$ be two intervals of the same lengh $|I|$. Also $I_i\cap I_j=\emptyset$ if $i\not=j$. May I know whether the following identity holds:
$$\dfrac{1}{|I|}E\big(1(X_k\in I_i)1(X_{k+1}\in I_j) \dfrac{1}{p_{X_k}(X_k)}\big)=P(X_{k+1}\in I_j\mid X_k\in I_i).$$

I have checked two special cases:

Case1: $X_{k+1}$ is independent of $X_k$, then RHS=$P(X_{k+1}\in I_j)$, while 
LHS is equal to 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{|I|}E\big(1(X_k\in I_i)1(X_{k+1}\in I_j)\dfrac{1}{p_{X_k}(X_k)}\big)
&=\dfrac{1}{|I|}E\big(1(X_k\in I_i)\dfrac{1}{p_{X_k}(X_k)}\big)P(X_{k+1}\in I_j)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{|I|}\bigg(\int_{I_i}\dfrac{p_{X_k}(x)}{p_{X_k}(x)}\, dx\bigg)P(X_{k+1}\in I_j)=P(X_{k+1}\in I_j),
\end{align*}
so the identity holds.

Case2: If $X_{k+1}=X_k$, then RHS=$\dfrac{P(X_{k}\in I_i\cap I_j)}{P(X_k\in I_i)}$, while LHS =$\dfrac{|I_i\cap I_j|}{|I_i|}$. By assumption of disjoint intervals, the identity holds.

May I know whether it holds in general? If necessary, we can also assume $X_k$ is independent of $X_{k+1}-X_k$.

Comment: No reason to expect equality in the general case.

Comment: @Did How about $X_k$ is good enough, say they are continuous random variables and has joint pdf?

Comment: The existence of PDFs is offtopic, simply write down the definitions of the LHS and of the RHS assuming some joint PDF and see how they differ.